# SQL join query performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
1. [User].[Users]

    --------------------------------------------------
    |[UserID]          | INT           (primary key) |
    |[Username]        | NVARCHAR(50)                |
    |[IsVerified]      | BIT                         |
    |[ModifiedDate]    | DATETIME                    |
    --------------------------------------------------

2. [User].[EmailAddresses]
    --------------------------------------------------
    |[UserID]          | INT          (foreign key)  |
    |[EmailAddressID]  | INT                         |
    |[EmailAddress]    | NVARCHAR(50)                |
    |[IsPrimary]       | BIT                         |
    |[IsVerified]      | BIT                         |
    |[ModifiedDate]    | DATETIME                    |
    --------------------------------------------------
```

Now, when I run this query, it performs great:

```
SELECT
  u.[UserID],
  u.[Username],
  u.[IsVerified],
  e.[EmailAddressID],
  e.[EmailAddress]
FROM [User].[Users] u
INNER JOIN [User].[EmailAddresses] e
  ON e.[UserID] = u.[UserID]
WHERE (@pEmailAddress = e.[EmailAddress])
AND (@pPassword = u.[Password])
```

**But**, when I run this query, it performs horribly:

```
SELECT
  u.[UserID],
  u.[Username],
  u.[IsVerified],
  e.[EmailAddressID],
  e.[EmailAddress],
  e.[IsPrimary],
  e.[IsVerified],
  e.[ModifiedDate]
FROM [User].[Users] u
INNER JOIN [User].[EmailAddresses] e
  ON e.[UserID] = u.[UserID]
WHERE (@pEmailAddress = e.[EmailAddress])
AND (@pPassword = u.[Password])
```

Note that I just add 1 from these 3 columns (`e.[IsPrimary]`, `e.[IsVerified]`, `e.[ModifiedDate]`), and it turns to perform horribly (5-6 seconds delay)...

What could it be? am I not joining the tables right? is it because I have some columns with the same name in both tables?

Also, I don't have many records... (about 20 records)...

**UPDATE:**
I found that "(@pPassword = u.[Password])" also removes the problem, it performs great without it, does it have something to do with indexing?

Here is the execution plan:

[image: Execution plan]

My indexes:

1. [User].[Users]:

> [UserID] (ASC) - Primary key

2. [User].[EmailAddresses]

> [UserID] (ASC), [EmailAddressID] (ASC) - Primary key
>
> [EmailAddress] (ASC) - Unique key

Comment: Have you checked the query plan?  In SQL Server Management Studio there is a button above the query that will run estimated plan upon execution.  This will offer you a visual step through of your query and show you the most expensive part of your query by percentage.  It will also suggest any indexes you should create.  Please run that and let us know what it comes back with.

Comment: @DomDaFonte Thanks, I added an execution plan...

Comment: No problem. In your query plan I see There is a clustered index scan on a phone field though I see no reference to phone numbers in there.  1. Run sp_spaceused for each table and send the results.  2. Can you right click the tables in Ssms, do a create like and post the ddl for each table?  3. Finally is the password field hashed?  I may be able to see this in the ddl, but let me know.

Comment: I created your tables and indexes and seeded them each with around 200 rows of relational data.  I have 0 issues.  I'm fairly certain you have more data in your table structure.  Especially given one of the clustered indexes being highlighted in the explain shows you are scanning on a phone number index.  Send some more info if you want help.

Comment: @DomDaFonte - I also have [User].[Phones] table, but for abstraction I decided to omit it, also the password field is hashed, I use Bcrypt, also I found an answer that is working for me... I turned both tables in the query, scroll down to view... thanks anyways.

Comment: ok that's good news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, though I don't if it's the right one, but seems to solve the issue, performance is great! instead of 5 seconds execution, it gets 0.365, this is great!

I didn't find anything wrong with my indexes, or in 1 of the 3 columns I added...

Basically, I changed the query - I turned both tables in the query, so if I had:

```
SELECT
  u.[UserID],
  u.[Username],
  u.[IsVerified],
  e.[EmailAddressID],
  e.[EmailAddress],
  e.[IsPrimary],
  e.[IsVerified],
  e.[ModifiedDate]
FROM [User].[Users] u
INNER JOIN [User].[EmailAddresses] e ON e.[UserID] = u.[UserID]
WHERE (@pEmailAddress = e.[EmailAddress]) AND (@pPassword = u.[Password])
```

Now, it is:

```
SELECT
  u.[UserID],
  u.[Username],
  u.[IsVerified],
  e.[EmailAddressID],
  e.[EmailAddress],
  e.[IsPrimary],
  e.[IsVerified],
  e.[ModifiedDate]
FROM [User].[EmailAddresses] e
INNER JOIN [User].[Users] u ON u.[UserID] = e.[UserID]
WHERE (e.[EmailAddress] = @pEmailAddress) AND (@pPassword = u.[Password])
```

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT u.[UserID], u.[Username], u.[IsVerified], e.[EmailAddressID],
       e.[EmailAddress], e.[IsPrimary], e.[IsVerified], e.[ModifiedDate]
FROM [User].[Users] u INNER JOIN
     [User].[EmailAddresses] e
      ON e.[UserID] = u.[UserID]
WHERE (@pEmailAddress = e.[EmailAddress]) AND (@pPassword = u.[Password]);
```

You want to try the following indexes:  `users(password, userid)` and `email(emailaddress, userid)`.

Comment: But without the 3 columns (e.[IsPrimary], e.[IsVerified], e.[ModifiedDate]) it performs great, I think it has nothing to do with index, these columns should not affect the performance, but somehow they do...

Answer (score 0):

Try running an explain or execution plan to see how it's executed.  The explain plan will tell you whether indexes or table scans are being used.  I am guessing the first query is able to use an index as a covered index to retrieve emailAddressID and emailAddress but the second query is required to read the actual table since it's returning columns not in the index.  If you don't have emailAddressID and emailAddress indexed, try adding them as an index.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a good solution as I can't test that but try following to see what will happen?

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT e.*
FROM [User].[Users] u
INNER JOIN [User].[EmailAddresses] e ON e.[UserID] = u.[UserID]
WHERE (@pEmailAddress = e.[EmailAddress]) AND (@pPassword = u.[Password])
)
SELECT [IsPrimary], [IsVerified], [ModifiedDate] 
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is covered by indexes, your second is not.

Assumptions: EmailAddress is unique, thus that index explicitly contains that field plus EmailAddressID and UserID if they are the clustered index.
--OR--

EmailAddressID and UserID are the PK and there is at least an index on EmailAddress.

When you add an additional field, that will lead to at least a seek+key lookup to retrieve the data from the table.

You may want an index containing the EmailAddress (since these are the field you are filtering by) and include the rest of the columns. (`INCLUDE` clause). This would render your index a covering index for your second query, therefore an index scan would be enough and no need for lookup.

Optionally you can try a similar covering index using UserID.

A query plan will help a lot to check which one is better (for your current data). Check it.